# Exporting networkD3 graphs as vector graphics

Tags: r, d3.js, svg, vector-graphics, networkd3

Assume a network graph generated via the R library [networkD3](https://christophergandrud.github.io/networkD3/). Assume further that you can save that network graph as an external stand alone HTML file (see section [Output](https://christophergandrud.github.io/networkD3/)) or, alternatively, render it via the R library [htmlwidgets](https://github.com/ramnathv/htmlwidgets).

Do you see any way to export a network so generated as a vector graphic (pdf or svg), irrespective of whether inside or outside of R?

*Note*: I understand that the primary purpose of the D3.js library is not to generate static data visualizations, but surely there is a way to use/convert D3 network graphs for print publication.

**Edit 1**:
Following the [suggestion by CJ Yetman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57751023/3981290), I inspected the DOM properties of the HTML file via Firefox Developer Edition. Using this method, it is possible to specifically see SVG properties (see [this example](https://pasteboard.co/IvwB3tt.png)), but they are mostly empty. However, how do I *'extract the SVG from the DOM'*, as CJ Yetman indicated?

Comment: I have used https://github.com/wch/webshot (the webshot package) to generate pdfs of htmls generated in R. Not perfect, but it works.

Comment: Do you want to extract the SVG file, or do you want an image (ie jpg or png?) I have some code for the latter if you like

Comment: @Mikkel I would specifically need a vector graphic such as an SVG file.

Answer (score 2):

Since you do mention htmlwidgets, I can share how I managed..

I have my `NetworkD3` app as a webpage (easiest you can just create an account with [shinyapps.io](https://www.shinyapps.io) and plug your code into their server for free through RStudio using a NetworkD3 shiny app template)

And then open your plot using Opera browser (did not work with Chrome) and right click on your plot and `Save as PDF...` this will give you vectorized figures that you can zoom in endlessly without losing resolution.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

View it in a browser and then use the browser’s developer tools to extract the SVG from the DOM... some browsers (I think Chrome) will even let you right click on an SVG to save it to your local drive. It has to be rendered in a browser first though, because the underlying JavaScript is what ultimately generates the SVG.

Using something like [SVG Crowbar](https://nytimes.github.io/svg-crowbar/) might make it even easier to save the SVG from a webpage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; it would be a straightforward approach, if it indeed works. I would need some additional information, though. I can inspect the DOM properties of the HTML file via Firefox Developer Edition and even see specifically the SVG properties (see: https://pasteboard.co/IvwB3tt.png). However, how do I *'extract the SVG from the DOM'*, as you indicated?

Comment: There are many questions on SO about extracting an SVG from a webpage. Maybe one of those will help with your specific use case.

Comment: This is an easy tool for saving SVGs from websites https://nytimes.github.io/svg-crowbar/

Comment: @CJYetman , SVG Crowbar is working fine for me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit of code... Let's assume that you have a chart rendered into a div with id="watcher".

```
<button onClick={() => alert(document.getElementById('watcher').innerHTML)} style={{ padding: '10px' }}>
    Show generated html/svg
</button>
```

[image: Screen shot of alert showing SVG code]

The above is code for React, but can be adapted for any environment.

You can therefore grab the rendered HTML into a variable with a line like this:

```
svgMarkup = document.getElementById('watcher').innerHTML
```

Basically it's a string, which you can then send to a backend for saving, or to file.

Another approach is to server side render the SVG and save it directly to the file without the need to display it. D3 should be able to handle that.